# How to dynamically assign each row in SQLSRV results to <td> element and make them clickable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, sqlsrv

I am very new to JS/PHP/web dev in general so apologies if this is a very basic question, but I'm trying to make each `<td>` element in a table clickable, and also get the text of that `<td>` on click.

Right now I have a SQL query that runs when a date input is selected, and returns a column of basketball game IDs that occurred on the date that is selected.

What I'm having trouble with is making each individual `<td>` clickable when the query populates the table. Currently my code works, but only the first `<td>` is clickable.

Here is the PHP code I have that gives me the Game IDs for the date selected (apologies for bad formatting)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>                
      <?php 
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      ?>
        <td id='matchuptable' onclick="game_ids()">
            <?php echo $row['GAME_ID']?>
        </td>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my JS function that is called when the `<td>` is clicked:

```
<script type=text/javascript src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function game_ids()
      {
          var gid = document.getElementById("matchuptable").innerText;
        alert(gid)
      $.post('gamelogs.php',{game_ids_name:gid},function(data){$('#gamelogs_here').html(data)})};
  </script>
```

I am positive there is a much much cleaner way to do this, and any tips/advice on formatting would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *id* attribute should be unique, I suggest you to add a counter and append it to your base id. You can also add a parameter to your *game_ids()* function and pass *this* (that represent the current element clicked), avoiding a DOM lookup:

```php
<tr>
    <?php
    $rowCount = 0;
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)):
        $rowCount++;
    ?>
        <td id="matchuptable-<?=$rowCount?>" onclick="game_ids(this)">
            <?php echo $row['GAME_ID']?>
        </td>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
</tr>
```

I've used the *while(): - endWhile;* syntax for better readability

In the JS code you get the clicked element as a parameter:

```js
function game_ids(el)
{
    alert(el.innerText);
    $.post('gamelogs.php',{game_ids_name:gid},function(data){$('#gamelogs_here').html(data)});
}
```